# Is there a more elegant way to get ripped corners/ edges for a duct-tape shader?

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm trying to make a duct-tape shader. I want the short edges/ corners ripped, not clean (as constant with a colorramp) but not completely shredded (with just noise). Every try with mixing them gives me not the optimal result.
What would be a controlable perhaps elegant way for that?

Bonus-question; I use two wave-nodes that control the bumps, how can i add them in a way that they lay on top of each other rather than mixing/ blending in the intersections?

Bonusquestion 2: How can I get a result, that i get no small parts/"islands" of duct-tape around the edges?

[image]

Comment: sorry, but here are strict rules: so just ask only one question, not 1 plus 2 bonus questions. You can open as many new questions as you want.